# Go from third of forth view controller to root view controller swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have 3 view controllers, presented modally, how do I dismiss the view controllers and go directly from the third right back to the first (root) view controller.

Basically, when I call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` from the third I want it to also dismiss the underlying second view controller and return straight to the first view, releasing the others from memory.

EDIT

Simply, want to go from the third view on the right, back to the first without having to go through and dismiss the middle on. Obviously I can't just present the first one form the third, as thats a massive memory leak.

[image]

Comment: You need to put everything in a container view controller and use the transitionFromViewController:toViewController: method.

Comment: Actually I've been able to connect a button to unwindToViewController (on the storyboard) and it dismisses all my viewcontrollers (modally presented).  If I ever need to do the same without a button maybe I'll use this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` for that.
You can post a notification when you want to dismiss all of your view controllers:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification("dismissNotification")
```

Then make these view controllers register to listen for such notifications in your `viewWillAppear` function:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("dismissFunction"), name: "dismissNotificaiton", object: nil)
```

Finally, you call `dismissViewController:` in your `dismissFunction`

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: 'dismissViewControllerAnimated' always seems to dismiss the top view controller, even if you prefix it with 'self' in the underlying view controller.

Comment: Hmm.. did you consider having the model view controllers set on another navigation controller? This way, if you dismiss the main navigation controller, all other controllers will be dismissed right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Let me know if that what you needed :)

Comment: that will remove the current view and reveal the underlying view controller. See my edit to make it clearer