# how to go to home page without storyboard by swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I have several viewcontrollers, and I want to have a work flow like below:

[image]

So MainController will create a tabbarcontroller which include A,B,C view controller. Then when user goes to B, will go to B-1, B-2 then back to MainController at the final.

How can I do with this flow?
Should I use popViewController? And if so, how ?

Comment: What is in MainController? The usual approach is to add a navigation controller after the tab controller and add controller B, B1, B2 to the stack.Return to rootviewcontroller using popToRootViewController(animated:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go from third of forth view controller to root view controller swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161259/go-from-third-of-forth-view-controller-to-root-view-controller-swift)

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani, the answer didn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to pop root view controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:  true)
```

Comment: This will only work if MainController is also inside a `UINavigationController`

Comment: Add BViewController in navigationController

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to work with **UINavigationController**.

Please check this example this example is perfect for your requirement.

[Swift Example](https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0)

[Apple example code (Objective-C)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html)

**Update**
[Another example](https://www.iosinsight.com/uinavigationcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard/)

Here I am not put example code please check above links for your reference.

Comment: But my rootViewControllr is a TabBar Controller

Comment: Yes I know but you need to setup TabBar and UINavigationController in this link explain how to setup TabBar and UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the hierarchy of your app, or its too complicated this one gets you the `UIViewController` you need.

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as! YourViewController
```

Comment: this will lead the app crash